# AJAX requests in Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my web application, what the user does on the page have to be sent my database, so I have the latest changes saved.

I just call the function with the request here when the user close the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = sendData;
```

But where the problems come up is when I send data every 10 second. I do send my requests sync and not async (or it would not be sent `onbeforeunload`). The problem is that this adds delays to the user interface when the data is sent every 10 second.

```
setInterval(sendData,10000);
```

This is what's getting called:

```
function sendData(){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var localData = datatodatabase;
     xhr.open("POST", "handler.php", false);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xhr.send("pack="+datatodatabase);
}
```

Is it possible to add this inside a Web Worker to make the synchronized requests stop delaying what everything else is going on?

(As I said: I have to use synchronized because of `onbeforeunload`)

Comment: I don't think so, becaus the communcation to the worker is async as well

Comment: The web workers belong to the page, so if you don't delay the page unload, its web workers will be automatically terminated as it unloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make it asynchronous every 10 seconds, but `onbeforeunload` make it synchronous? Like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    sendData(true);
}, 10000);

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    sendData(false);
}

function sendData(async) {
    // Make the ajax call the specific way based on whether *async* is *true* or *false*

    // Probably eventually:
    xhr.open("POST", "handler.php", async);
}
```

Comment: Like this: `xhr.open("POST", "handler.php", async);` ?

Comment: Actually, yeah I guess so. The reason I hadn't suggested that is because when dealing with the response of that AJAX request, it's different between asynchronous and synchronous requests. With async, you use `onreadystatechange` because you don't know when the response will come back - so you bind a listener for it. With sync, you can retrieve the response on the line after sending. In your case, if you're not worried about the response, then yes, just use that code you suggested.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from waiting for a response from the server? (Btw, the code works awesome!)